# How to change the background color of a screen area on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website for a school project, wherein I have left and right drawers. The drawers are hidden and show only when onclick `pageX < 100` (left drawer) and `pageX > 1200` (right drawer). As the drawers show only `onclick()`, I want that area to get highlighted in some way (preferably color-change) so that the user knows there is something there. How do I do this?

#### HTML:

```
  <div id="pgcontainer"> 
    <header>
      <div id="navbar">
        <div id="rightdrawer">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="archives.html">Archives</a></li>
            <li><a href="contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="sponsors.html">Our sponsors</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  var menuwidth  = 240; // pixel value for sliding menu width
  var menuspeed  = 400; // milliseconds for sliding menu animation time

  var $bdy       = $('body');
  var $container = $('#pgcontainer');
  var $hamburger    = $('#hamburgermenu');
  var $rightmenu = $('#rightdrawer');
  var negwidth   = "-"+menuwidth+"px";
  var poswidth   = menuwidth+"px";

  $('#pgcontainer').on('click',function(e) {
    if(e.pageX < 130) {
      if($bdy.hasClass('openmenu')) {
        jsAnimateMenuLeft('close');
      } else {
        jsAnimateMenuLeft('open');
      }
    }
  });

  $('.overlay').on('click', function(e) {
    if($bdy.hasClass('openmenu')) {
      jsAnimateMenuLeft('close');
    }
    else if($bdy.hasClass('openmenur')) {
      jsAnimateMenuRight('close');
    }
  });

  $('a[href$="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  function jsAnimateMenuLeft(tog) {
    if(tog == 'open') {
      $bdy.addClass('openmenu');

      $container.animate({marginRight: negwidth, marginLeft: poswidth}, menuspeed);
      $hamburger.animate({width: poswidth}, menuspeed);
      $('.overlay').animate({left: poswidth}, menuspeed);
    }

    if(tog == 'close') {
      $bdy.removeClass('openmenu');

      $container.animate({marginRight: "0", marginLeft: "0"}, menuspeed);
      $hamburger.animate({width: "0"}, menuspeed);
      $('.overlay').animate({left: "0"}, menuspeed);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: may be you should make overlay divs from left and right of 100px width, and change their color on hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the optimal solution here is to add two more elements, position them fixed and add some nice hover styles.

Note that since `.leftdrawer-hover` and `.rightdrawer-hover` are children on `#pgcontainer` clicking on them would act exactly as you need, because click events will bubble to `#pgcontainer` where you will detect them and show/hide corresponding drawer.

```css
#pgcontainer .leftdrawer-hover,
#pgcontainer .rightdrawer-hover {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 130px;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(200, 200, 200, .4);
}
#pgcontainer .rightdrawer-hover {
    right: 0;
}
#pgcontainer .leftdrawer-hover:hover,
#pgcontainer .rightdrawer-hover:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="pgcontainer">
    <div class="leftdrawer-hover"></div>
    <div class="rightdrawer-hover"></div>
    <!-- other tags -->    
</div>
```